# Mass Video Trimming

Tags: windows, video, video-editing

I have a bunch of videos created with a 10 second intro in the front of each of them. They are all MP4 and basically I want to trim the first 10 seconds off each video. Is there a piece of software that lets me do this as a mass. That is without having to click through each one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)
- Allows to [trim](https://superuser.com/q/138331/116475): e.g. to cut the first 2 seconds: `ffmpeg -ss 2 -i input.flv -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.flv`
- Is CLI so you can batch.

Comment: I'm using this code to batch them: `for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -ss 10 -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"`and then a new line:
`pause`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Mencoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder) (part of MPlayer HQ):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on [Windows](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html)
- Allows to [trim](https://superuser.com/q/258032/116475): e.g. to cut the first 2 seconds: `mencoder.exe -ss 2 -oac copy -ovc copy input.flv -o output.flv` (Mencoder uses FFmpeg, hence the similar syntax)
- Is CLI so you can batch.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/):

- Free and open-source
- Runs on Windows
- Allows to [trim](http://avidemux.org/smuf/index.php?topic=10280.0)
- Can [batch operations through scripting](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=tutorial%3abatch_processing).

Comment: Im trying this now

Comment: @kdogisthebest Frankly I'd try FFmpeg first, I haven't used Avidemux for a long time but AFAIR FFmpeg is smoother (at least it was the case a few years ago) :)
E.g. [Is it possible to use ffmpeg to trim off X seconds from the beginning of a video with an unspecified length?](http://superuser.com/q/258032/116475)