# Trimming video files

Tags: video, video-editing, quality-assurance

I am having trouble trimming video files. I tried using Windows Movie Maker, and think I inputted all the video specs accurately, but the video file it outputs is horrendously lag-ridden. I then tried Avidemux and had similar quality issues.  Surely there's a way to simply cut the beginning and/or end off of a video file without "re-writing" or "re-encoding" (not sure of the term) the entire video, and utterly destroying quality in the process. I feel like the things I'm trying are overkill for the problem.

My OS is Windows 7, and I am looking for a free, simple program for this very basic task.  I am willing to sacrifice decorative options for simplicity and to preserve the integrity of the output video quality.

Comment: Did you try the options provided in: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/mass-video-trimming ?

Comment: Your question is a bad fit for this site. Can you [edit] and make it request for software? "I need a program to do X and it has to meet the following requirements: ...." Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information

Comment: @RockPaperLizard:  I could try those, although I think the question is addressing a different issue.

Comment: You haven't provided enough info.  Are you looking for a free solution or paid?  Any other requirements?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What Operating system are you using? Would a command line tool be okay? If you export the video with Movie Maker in a different format, do the lags go away?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I don't see how you could view a video on the command line to know where to trim it.  Movie Maker only allowed me to export to .wmv format.

Comment: @user12806 Imagine a movie series that begins with 35 seconds of intro each. You don't need to see the movie to know that you need to cut out 35 seconds, do you? For this (or situations like this) a command line tool is sufficient.

Comment: @user12806 Or you use one tool to learn the appropriate position (a regular video-player) and then a command line tool to do the trimming.